# how can change color drawing of mupdf?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, signature, mupdf

i'm new android deverloper. My project is using mupdf for android to sign to pdf file.I am using source code mupdf for androd(source code here https://github.com/muennich/mupdf/tree/master/android) you can down it try to run it because i have changed some thing on this courceto merger with my old source. I can sign to pdf file with mupdf liblary. But i have some problem when i want to change color of signture. I found the code to set color for signture and had changed color form red to black(code on file PageView.java https://github.com/muennich/mupdf/blob/master/android/src/com/artifex/mupdfdemo/PageView.java )at

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(INK_THICKNESS*scale);
                    paint.setColor(INK_COLOR);
                    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

but when i click button acept my draw. color of signature back to red..Please some one give me some solution. thank for any comment and sorry for my bad English....

Answer (score 0):

Look in mupdf/platform/android/jni/mupdf.c, function MuPDFCore_addInkAnnotationInternal. There you will see that the color is hardwired to red with the lines

```
color[0] = 1.0;
color[1] = 0.0;
color[2] = 0.0;
```

If you simply wish to hardwire it to black, then change 1.0 to 0.0.

If you wish the resulting Ink annotation to show up in the printed version of the PDF then in the function pdf_create_annot in file pdf-annot.c, you should add the line:

```
pdf_dict_puts_drop(annot_obj, "F", pdf_new_int(doc, F_Print));
```

after the line:

```
pdf_dict_puts_drop(annot_obj, "Rect", pdf_new_rect(doc, &rect));
```

Comment: thank for comment. i aslo think that.  Now i have new problem. Counld you help me.  When i print my pdf file (it contain signature) my signature is gone. If i change for print format to jpg i can see and print file have sinature but my file is blur.:(.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an explanation of how to ensure the annotation prints

Comment: thank :D.. so do you know any way to modify pdf file. Because my pdf is modify my signture after i sign. The signature is able to see but when i print pdf it is gone. and   i see it just is a image be attach with pdf file not modified.:(. Any solotion ?

Comment: @PaulGardiner can you tell how can save annotation for password protected pdf?